# how to use TOR combined with a VPN

Tags: vpn

I use Nord VPN. Then I istalled TOR.
Now checking the used IP, TOR and VPN gives me a different one.
My question: How to "combine" TOR and VPN so the TOR is using the VPN?
Many thank´s!
Joe

Answer (score 1):

Just connect your vpn software and then after your vpn software is connected open tor.